# Expressjs - simple find and replace in index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using expressjs to run my server and have set up the default route for static content as follows: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname.substr(0, __dirname.lastIndexOf('/')), 'public')));`, where all my static assets are found in `public/src`, `public/styles` etc...

Now I want to do a simple find and replace on in `public/index.html` but as it is in my static folder it ignores any routes I subsequently set up for `app.get('/, function  ...`.

Is there a way I can apply some preprocessing to index.html without having to move all my other static files into a subdirectory e.g. can `express.static()` be passed an ignore list somehow?

Comment: try putting the static middleware after your routes, also app.get on / is not the same as app.get on /index.html

Comment: @r043v - Doesn't work unfortunately, trying lots of different orders, both within and without `app.configure()`

Comment: try with http://pastebin.com/JVdu6XBt before it work, after it's not

Comment: I also have `app.get('/*', function (req, res, next){
    res.writeHead(301, {
        Location: '/'
    });
    res.end();
});`, (temporary disabling of deep linking) which it turns out is a complicating factor

Answer (score 1):

Set up your app to use your routes before using static:

```
app.use(app.router);  // Make sure this gets called *before* the next line
app.use(express.static(...));
```

Comment: the static routes don't seem to take effect unless they're inside an app.configure( ...), which I assume always gets applied before the routes. If I put my other routes inside configure( ... ) then they fail instead.

Comment: Are you explicitly calling `app.use(app.router)` anywhere? When you do `app.get(...)` or `app.post(...)` routes, it gets called behind the scenes, but you should be able to ensure that your routes get called before `static` if you call it yourself.

Comment: Fter reading that I thin kmy problem is I want my /|/index.html route attempted first, then my statics, then my /* route (for disabling deep linking). I guess I just need to use a less aggressive path string than '/*'